# How to convert text to table rows in the OpenOffice?

Tags: openoffice.org

I have a table with cell that contains several paragraphs. I want to split it into multiple table rows in such a way that one row has text from one paragraph.

For example, I have such table:

[image]

And I want to make the following table:
[image]

I have found [Table -> Convert -> Text To Table](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/FAQ/Writer/FormattingPagesAndDocuments/How_do_I_convert_structured_text_into_a_table%3F) feature, but it creates new a table inside the cell:
[image]